# Python list: after m items skip n items

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have the following list:

```
x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

After `m=3`items, we would like to skip `n=2` items so that we have the following list:

```
x=[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and mods to achieve this irrespective of the actual values in the list:

```py
num_to_skip = 2
num_to_retain = 3
length = num_to_skip + num_to_retain
# the remainders of the indexes to exclude from the list
exclude_remainders = range(num_to_retain, length)

xs = range(10)
zs = [
  x for i, x in enumerate(xs) 
  if i % length not in exclude_remainders
]

# => [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

i.e. what this is doing is:

```
     0  1  2  3  4   5  6  7  8  9   10 11 ->
1.  [-------------] [-------------] [----->
2.           [----]          [----]

1 - for each of these sets:
2 - exclude the values where the remainder obtained by modding the 
    index against the length of the set is not in a list of 
    remainders to exclude

i.e. exclude the following:
index % 5 == 3, and
index % 5 == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flattened list of slices in a simple list comprehension:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

take = 3
skip = 2

[n for i in range(0, len(x), take+skip) 
 for n in x[i: i + take]]
# [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15]
```

This iterates over the range by 5 (`take + skip`) and then takes the first three starting at that index `x[i: i + take]`.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to speed this up?

Comment: When I time this, it takes 54ms for a list with 1 million items. How fast does it have to be? How big is your input?

Comment: There isn't a target; I am just wondering if it's possible to speed it up.

Comment: @user572780 yes, you should be able to speed this up by making a generator that skips the entries you want. The slices above create ephemeral lists, which eats up time. You might try Larry's below, which avoids this at the slight expense of readability.

Comment: ...actually @user572780 just tried the other code and it came in significantly slower. So not really sure other than working with something like Numpy.

Comment: @Mark that wouldn't necessarily speed it up. Iterating over a generator often takes longer than just creating a list.

Comment: Yeah @juanpa.arrivillaga, I tried it and couldn't make anything that wasn't a lot slower.

Comment: @Mark a divide and conquer strategy _may_ be faster - split the list into lists of length n (in this case, 5), then use async.gather to concurrently process all lists, then flatten the result